# How to properly share an object between different app pages in Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I have implemented an arbitrary class which has some states and need to be shared between different pages in Flutter. What I am currently doing is I defined a `sqflite` database helper and each page loads that object form database and before going to other pages, it saves it again to the database and navigates to other page. However, it adds many complexities and bugs.

Another possible solution could be add it to `myApp()` class which is called in `main()` function. However, since other pages do not inherit `myApp()`, they have no access to `global_object`.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{

// I need gloabl_object accessible in different pages
//--------------------------------------------------- 
MyObject global_object; 
//---------------------------------------------------

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App title',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        // App theme
      ),
      //home: Homepage(),
      routes: { // Defining routs
        // DIFFERENT PAGES THAT NEEDS TO HAVE ACCESS TO global_object
      },
    );
}
```

Comment: Let me save you some headache later. Don't declare global objects. Use a package like provider or get_it. You'll thank me later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**: Use package get_it https://pub.dev/packages/get_it 
Simple direct `Service Locator` that allows to decouple the interface from a concrete implementation and to access the concrete implementation from everywhere in your App. 
example https://github.com/fluttercommunity/get_it/tree/master/example/lib

```
GetIt sl = GetIt.instance;

void main() {

  sl.registerSingleton<AppModel>(AppModelImplementation());

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

After register , you can access everywhere with

```
var myAppModel = sl.get<AppModel>();
```

**Method 2**: Use package provider https://pub.dev/packages/provider 
full example https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/provider_shopper

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Using MultiProvider is convenient when providing multiple objects.
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        // In this sample app, CatalogModel never changes, so a simple Provider
        // is sufficient.
        Provider(create: (context) => CatalogModel()),
        // CartModel is implemented as a ChangeNotifier, which calls for the use
        // of ChangeNotifierProvider. Moreover, CartModel depends
        // on CatalogModel, so a ProxyProvider is needed.
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<CatalogModel, CartModel>(
          create: (context) => CartModel.empty(),
          update: (context, catalog, previousCart) =>
              CartModel(catalog, previousCart),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Provider Demo',
        theme: appTheme,
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => MyCatalog(),
          '/cart': (context) => MyCart(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

access with `Provider.of<CartModel>(context);`

```
class _CartList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var itemNameStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.title;
    var cart = Provider.of<CartModel>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: cart.items.length,
```

or with `Consumer<CartModel>`

```
class _CartTotal extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var hugeStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4.copyWith(fontSize: 48);

    return SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Consumer<CartModel>(
                builder: (context, cart, child) =>
                    Text('\$${cart.totalPrice}', style: hugeStyle)),
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive solution.